# How to select only the unique records

Tags: mysql, sql

By that I mean leaving any duplicate records

For example

```
ID  NAME
1   a
2   a
3   b
4   b
5   c
```

Desired output.

5 c  only

I am tired of trying this . So I don't think I don't have any reasonably code to paste here .

Comment: @UncleIroh it looks like he only wants records that aren't duplicated. So `distinct` isn't applicable here.

Comment: @Jonno_FTW yeah sorry deleted my comment once I realized that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another possible way:

```
select min(id), name from table group by name having count(*) = 1
```

Comment: while this works for his example set, in the general sense I think min() will not work.

Comment: @UncleIroh In this case it should, because we are limiting the query to unique records only (i.e. the `having count(*) = 1` clause), which *guarantees* that each group will only have one record and thus the `min()` function has no effect on the results (as there is only one set per group). The only reason its there is because there is a `group by` in the query and the `id` column is not grouped, so it needs to be inside an aggregate function.

Comment: It seems its working without the min . I got to test well though.

Comment: @Narayan It will work without the `min()` in MySQL, and will probably give you the same results in this specific case, but you shouldn't do that. Its a major oversight in MySQL's design that it allows such a query to run without an aggregate function, and this "feature" shouldn't be used... However, in your specific case, the results will most likely be exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way:

```
select t.*
from table t
where not exists (select 1
                  from table t2
                  where t2.name = t.name and t2.id <> t.id
                 );
```

Here is another way:

```
select t.*
from table t join
     (select name, count(*) as cnt
      from table t
      group by name
      having cnt = 1
     ) tt
     on tt.name = t.name;
```

Comment: I think you want t2.id <> t.id  in your first example

Comment: @UncleIroh is right, you need to check when ids are not equal, otherwise the first one does not return any results.

Answer (score 0):

I think the cleanest way to do this is to select the name and id for each row, group by the name, and filter only on values that have a COUNT(*) of 1. This means any rows that have a name that is not unique are excluded.

It would look like this:

```
SELECT id, name
FROM myTable
GROUP BY name
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1;
```

I can't get SQL to work, but verified this in MySQL workbench:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is yet another way to do it:

```
SELECT * FROM table AS A 
   WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table AS T 
            WHERE T.NAME = A.NAME) = 1
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select a.* 
from table a
left join table b on a.name = b.name and a.id <> b.id
where b.id is null;
```